# Why doesn't Express render my React app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, reactjs, webpack

I'm building a React app w/Express. My server works fine, my Webpack creates my js file w/o issues but for some reason my App doesn't render.

Here is my test app:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Application from './Application';

console.log('works!');


function TestApp({}) {
  return (
    <div className="TestApp">Does this work?</div>
  );
}


render(<TestApp />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Here is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <title>React Test App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root" />
    <script src="js/bundle.js" async />
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is my `webpack.config.js` file:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, './app/assets/js/'),
  entry: './bundle',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './public/assets/js/'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: "/js/",
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx', '.json']
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compress: {
        warnings: false
      }
    }),
  ],
  module: {
    preLoaders: [{
      test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
      loader: 'eslint-loader',
      exclude: /node_modules/,
    }],
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'babel-loader',
    }, {
      test: /\.css$/,
      loader: 'style!css',
    }, ]
  },
  watch: true
};
```

and here is my middleware:

```
var express = require('express.io');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var path = require('path');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(express.compress());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './public/assets')));

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, './app/views'));

router = express.Router();

  router.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.render("index.ejs");
  });

  app.use("/", router);

app.listen(port, function (error) {
  return error 
    ? console.error(error) 
    : console.info("Listening on port %s", port);
});
```

Any clue what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: could it be the type res.render( "index.ejs" ); I assume it should be "index.js"

Comment: That depends, is the html you provided inside of your index.ejs file?

Comment: only real 1337 h4xx0rs can use react.

Comment: @BradColthurst Yes, that's the html from my index.ejs file.

Comment: @fayzaan Why would I render `index.js`? There is no `index.js` file. Also, `res.render()` compiles the template.

Comment: Alright that should be ok then, as @hansn mentioned below, it looks like the issue is the entry point in your `webpack.config.js`, it should point to the file that is responsible for kicking off your app. In this case that would appear to be the first block of code you posted (maybe named TestApp.js?), where you `render()` your TestApp component to the DOM.

Comment: @BradColthurst Tried all of these things without success. Also, the name of the `.js` file is `bundle.js` Webpack doesn't require the `.js` extention for the `entry` point because it assumes `.js` is the extension.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you'll want to change `res.render("index.ejs");` with `res.sendfile("index.html");`

Edit: On second thought; the `entry` field in webpack.config.js doesn't look right. It should point to you base javascript file. Does your bundle contain anything with the current configuration?

Comment: "Does your bundle contain anything with the current configuration?" I'm not sure what you mean but there are no errors in my terminal console and the js files seems to be compiling just fine.

Comment: @Wilhelm to check if it's bundling the correct files you can check if you can find the same code in both places - in the actual files and in the bundle. Also it's kind of strange if your main javascript file is called 'bundle', it should least have a .js extension, so try and change the entry field to your main javascript file and see what happens.

Comment: Tried all of these things without success. Also, the name of the `.js` file is `bundle.js` Webpack doesn't require the `.js` extention for the `entry` option because it assumes `.js` is the extension.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is 4 years old, but usually with `res.render()` for EJS extensions you don't need to add that. So putting

```
res.render(index);
```

should be fine